# Delphi - DBGrid last row focus on another component

Tags: delphi

I have a DBGrid linked to a dataset and I type values ​​in a column of that dbgrid, my question is how to do it when I get to the last row of that column of the DBGrid/Dataset when pressing Enter to focus on another TMemo component for example.

[image]

Comment: When you say " to focus on another TMemo component", do you want Enter to take to to the TMemo or not, and if not what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Sorry if you are confused but, yes I want to take it to the TMemo component.